# K-NN in R : Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, knn

I am running K-NN in R and keep getting the following error while I try to run the For loop for different 'k' values:

> Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :    ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors.

My variable 'Class' in this code (class_pred_valid$Class) is a factor with two levels 'used' and 'not used'. Is this could be the reason it is throwing an error? If yes, how do I overcome this issue. I have spent two days trying to solve it but couldn't. Thank you for providing any help.

```
    test.pred<-knn(class_pred_train[,-1], class_pred_test[,-1], class_pred_train[,1], k=25)
    table(class_pred_test[,1],test.pred)
    
    
    CrossTable(x=class_pred_test[,1] ,y=test.pred,prop.chisq = FALSE) # create a X-table 
    
    corr.class.rate<-numeric(25)
    
for(k in 1:25)
    {
      pred.class<-knn(class_pred_train[,-1], class_pred_valid[,-1], class_pred_train[,1], k=k)
      corr.class.rate[k]<-sum((pred.class=class_pred_valid$Class))/length(pred.class)
    }
    
    corr.class.rate
    
    plot(c(1:25),corr.class.rate,type="l",
         main="Correct Classification Rates for the Test Data for a range of k",
         xlab="k",ylab="Correct Classification Rate",cex.main=0.7)
    
    which.max(corr.class.rate)
    
    pred<-knn(class_pred_train[,-1], class_pred_test[,-1], class_pred_train[,1], k=1)
    sum((pred==class_pred_train$Class))/length(pred)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `==` instead of `=` inside the loop in the second line?

Comment: @dcarlson, thank you, that indeed was the mistake in my code. What a stupid oversight.